# Is it possible to change/enlarge font?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, design, font

Latex is very hard to read especially with complicated expressions that involve powers etc.

Is it possible to change font to Modern Computer and make it larger?

Right now I have to zoom in to read some mathematical expressions even though my monitor has a very dense resolution.

Answer (score 8):

$$
e^{\int_0^1 \log(1-x^2)\,dx}
$$

Right click on the math, go to `Math Settings > Scale All Math...` and enter your favorite number bigger than 100.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working on meta for me but it does work on the main site.  I use Chrome.

Comment: You can also define a Zoom Trigger which only actives the math zoom when the trigger is set.